# soundPool don't play inside loop at onAnimationStart

Tags: android, animation, soundpool

I have an array of ImageView that ImageViews will scale after each other.
Now i want to play short ding sound ( duration is less than a minute ) at onAnimationStart of animation at a loop.

Everything work right **but** the sound play only for first one.

```
public void AnimationAtEnd() {

    for (ck = 0; ck < totalCount; ck++) {

            ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1.6f,0f,1.6f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

            scale.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            scale.setStartOffset(ck * 600);
            scale.setDuration(600);
            scale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {    
                       mySoundPool.play(2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);          
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            images_cen[ck].startAnimation(scale);

        }
    }
}
```

and here is how i **define** soundPool and load sounds.

```
mySoundPool = new SoundPool(
                3,
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                0
        );
    mySoundPool.load(this, R.raw.circuit, 1);
    mySoundPool.load(this, R.raw.ding, 1);
    mySoundPool.load(this, R.raw.block, 1);
```

**How can i do that ??? or What's the problem ???**

PS1:

OK i add `soundPool.play()` to `onAnimationEnd` and it work fine . So there is nothing wrong with soundPool . I think It's from Animation side

Comment: ok . i add soundPool.play at onAnimationEnd and everything work fine !!! is there difference between onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd structure ?

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem, but is there a reason you're throwing away the `soundID` returned by `SoundPool.load`, and then using a hardcoded value of 2 as the `soundID` in your `play()` call?

Comment: @MattGibson You are right . The correct way is your suggestion but there is only 3 :) it was easier to hardcoding instead of using sound id ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onAnimationStart` will be called shortly after `images_cen[ck].startAnimation(scale);` even though you set the `startOffset` of the `Animation`.

I suggest you use `Animator` instead.

```
ObjectAnimator scale = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(images_cen[ck],
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 0, 1.6f),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 0, 1.6f)
                    );
scale.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
scale.setStartDelay(ck * 600);
scale.setDuration(600);
final View view = images_cen[ck];
scale.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mySoundPool.play(2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
scale.start();
```

Comment: You are right . the problem was exactly what you say but now where should i add `images_cen[ck].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` . I want to set the visibility when animation start .

Comment: In `onAnimationStart`.

Comment: i do this but i got error and i think its because of ck value will change when onAnimationStart call . it will reach the amount of array

Comment: I edit my answer. Use `final` variable reference to the `View`.